# Eazfuscator.NET 3.3 does not support .NET 4.5, but I can still obfuscate my project that has .NET 4.5 target framework. What am I not understanding?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, obfuscation, eazfuscator

Eazfuscator.NET was free until version 3.3, everywhere I have been reading says 3.3 does not contain .NET 4.5 support (support was released in v3.4), but I can obfuscate my project that is built against .NET 4.5.

What am I not seeing?

[Link talking about last free version](http://favsoft.blogspot.com/2012/08/eazfuscator-net-gone-commercial.html)

[Eazfuscator changelog page for version 3.3](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net/download/changes/3.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume either your code will have only the "non-4.5" parts obfuscated (obfuscators don't necessarily obfuscate everything in your code) or you haven't used any exclusive feature introduced by .NET 4.5 (think async and await, for example), so it obfuscates correctly even if you're targetting .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Eazfuscator.NET 3.3 works for you is related to specifics of your code.

Sooner or later you may get to the point where some .NET 4.5 constructs won't be correctly handled by the old version of Eazfuscator.NET. Once that happens, you get either an error during obfuscation or a broken assembly at the output.